# Please explain RegExp javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm experiencing some understanding problem of javascript RegExp behavior. Please help me to get how this stuff works.

```
var str = "_prefix_123 blah blah _prefix_321 blah blah blah _prefix_100500";
var prefix = "_prefix_";
var exp = new RegExp (prefix+"\d*","gm");

str1 = str.replace(exp,"hello");
alert(str1);

str2 = str.replace(/_prefix_\d*/gm, "hello");
alert(str2);
```

**check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6PSdg/4/**

For some reason two identical (at least they seem like) regex patterns return different results. Can anyone explain what's going on? ))

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you use the `RegExp` constructor, you're passing in a *string*, and backslashes in string literals are interpreted as *string* escapes. So to actually pass a backslash to the regex engine, you have to make sure the backslash in the string is escaped (by putting a backslash in front of it):

```
var exp = new RegExp (prefix+"\\d*","gm");
// Here ----------------------^
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PSdg/5/)